# React mapping an array of objects and filter it out

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to reactjs. The data is retrieved from the redux action and store as props.

I want to iterate through an array of objects and search a tour which match the tourId in the params but can not figure it out. In my console, I always got variable undefined.

Any ideas?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GefIC.png)

My data looks like this

```
[
  { 
    "_id": "12345",
    "name": "I am first tour",
    "description": "Iasofisajdaiosjdioasdmoias",
    "imageUrl": "https://something1.jpg",
    "dates": [
      "2021-06-19T09:00:00.000Z",
      "2021-07-20T09:00:00.000Z",
    ],
  },
  { 
    "_id": "67890",
    "name": "I am second tour",
    "description": "cvxbcvbcxbcvbcxb",
    "imageUrl": "https://something2.jpg",
    "dates": [
      "2023-01-12T09:00:00.000Z",
      "2023-04-22T01:00:00.000Z",
    ],
  },
   
  //.....rest data
]
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Tour.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Tour extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            currentTour: [],
        }
        this.findSingletour = this.findSingletour.bind(this);
    }


  componentDidUpdate() {
    const tourId = this.props.match.params._id;
    const FilteredTour = this.findSingletour(tourId);

    //FilteredTour is undefined. Can't set the state
    console.log(FilteredTour);
        if (FilteredTour !== this.state.currentTour) {
            this.setState({
                currentTour: FilteredTour
            });
        }
  }

    findSingletour = (tourId) => {
        const notYetFilterTours = this.props.tours.tourState.data;
        let filtered = [];
        // search through the array of objects and find out the tour based on tourId
        if (notYetFilterTours) {
            filtered = notYetFilterTours.find((tour) => {
                if (tour.id === tourId) return true;

                return filtered;
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const {name, description, imageUrl, dates} = this.state.currentTour;

        // this.state.currentTour is undefined
        console.log('from currentTour', this.state.currentTour);

        return (
            <div className="tour-container">
                <span>{name}</span>
                <span>{description}</span>
                <span>{imageUrl}</span>
                <span>{dates[0]}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    tours: state.tourStorer,
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
)(Tour);
```

Comment: (Updated) FilteredTour and this.state.currentTour are undefined. Which life cycle method should I use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you are doing "notYetFilterTours.map" and then doing find?

Have you tried by directly doing a find on "notYetFilterTours" like "notYetFilterTours.find(id => tour.id === tourId)"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
  findSingletour = (tourId) => {
    const notYetFilterTours = this.props.tours.data;
    let filtered = [];
    if(notYetFilterTours.length){
      // search through the array of objects and find out the tour based on tourId
      // error
      /*
      notYetFilterTours.map((notYetFilterSingleTour, index) => {
          return notYetFilterSingleTour.find((tour) => tour.id === tourId);
      }
      */
      filtered = notYetFilterTours.filter((tour, index) => {
        if(tour.id === tourId) return true;
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  };

// componentDidUpdate() should be used carefully, 
componentDidUpdate() {
    const tourId = this.props.match.params._id;
    const FilteredTour = this.findSingletour(tourId);

    // You should check your state like this...
    if (FilteredTour !== this.state.currentTour) {
      this.setState({
        currentTour: FilteredTour
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! But this.state.currentTour is still an empty array. How do I update the state?

Comment: I've uploaded an image to show my problem.